# A problem of Logarithm

Tags: logarithms

Find the minimum value of $$\frac{\log_bc}{\log a} + \frac{\log_ca}{\log b} + \frac{\log_ab}{\log c}$$

since I do not know how to write log base a index a so I gave it in that manner.
I tried out the problem and thought intuitively that the answer should be $1$ but cant find properly any reason.

Comment: upper log is like this $\log_b c$ and what is the base in denominator

Comment: Is anything else given? Like $\log a, \log b, \log c > 0$ or something?

Comment: @iostream007, why did you edit it this way? I am not sure what you wrote is correct. As for the the base is, it must be $e$ or $10$. But does it matter?

Comment: @soumyajit Am I edit it correctly?

Comment: @Soumajit, if you don't reply to any questions asked, obviously no one is gonna bother to answer your question.

Comment: @ParthThakkar In question he mentioned that he couldn't write base and index in log so he wrote in that way so I thought he wanted to write this.

Comment: Ok, then maybe I didn't understand him properly. But this is irritating, both of us are working at his problem and he isn't even interested.

Comment: @Soumajit, what are you intending to ask? please clarify, otherwise we can't answer.

Comment: I think, there must be some constraints on $a,b,c$ to get some interesting answer.

Comment: @iostream007 I suspect the intention was $\log_a (bc) + \log_b (ca) + \log_c (ab)$. That would lead to a classical minimisation problem.

Comment: @DanielFischer asker is not interested in replying so I'm not giving any effort

Comment: The OP may not have good Internet connection. Maybe has three kids and five cats and right now cannot reply. The good thing about this site is that your effort is not required for it to work.

Comment: the editing is wrong......

Comment: the thing is log in which base is a and index contains bc simmillarly the others....\

Comment: now i have found my solution......

Answer (score 1):

The expression is the same as 
$$\frac{\log(c)}{\log(a)\log(b)}+\frac{\log(a)}{\log(b)\log(c)}+\frac{\log(b)}{\log(a)\log(c)}$$

Fix $a$ and $b$, and make $c$ tend to $0$. What do you get?